# Configuring Spring Cloud Zuul Gateway to support multiple api versions

Tags: spring, netflix-zuul

I am trying to figure out entries required in zuul(version 1.3.0) configuration to support multiple versions of same api. Example Service 'A' has multiple versions viz v1, v2 and v3 each of the services are running using different spring profiles on different ports. Service name is same and not different for different api versions. Service 'A' is registered in eureka server and all instances are listed in eureka registry.

How can zuul application.yml be configured to support routing and load balancing request to v1, v2 and v3 versions of apis.

What will be approach in case Service 'B' which also has v1,v2 and v3 versions wants to call v1,v2 and v3 of Service 'A' through eureka registry.

Comment: Does your URL have anything in the path that represents the version?

Comment: Yes version number is in url example /service/v1/resource and /service/v2/resource

Comment: See this section of the Spring Cloud documentation. It covers this specific use-case.
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#_strangulation_patterns_and_local_forwards